# Github access credentials not accepted when trying to push to GitHub

Tags: flutter, android-studio, github, push, credentials

I am currently learning how to create apps with Flutter. I am using Android Studio and am a total beginner. I am not very familiar with GitHub.

I am simply trying to upload a project im working on to GitHub. However when I try to push to github, I'm asked for some HTTP access credential rather than my GitHub account access credentials and it keeps getting rejected.

On the GitHub side I have...

1. Created a free account
2. Setup a public repository ready to save my project to

On the Android Studio side i have...

1. installed Git,
2. enabled Version Control Integration with GIT
3. Added my files to GIT and committed directory

I have basically followed everything in this tutorial up until 4:50.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhfJTOu3_SE

The problem is when I try to 'PUSH' to github...

It asks me to Log In via GitHub, then I get the two screens in the screenshot.. I'm using Flutter and Dart so I guess the JetBrains IDE message is fine? But when I click 'Authorise in GitHub' I get a login dialog that looks more like I'm trying to login to my router admin settings or something...

My GitHub username and password are not accepted.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per github change , you need to generate token  check this link :
https://techglimpse.com/git-push-github-token-based-passwordless/

in android Studio :
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realise password access was deprecated.